# Custom ArrayAdapter for ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have implemented a custom array adapter for my ListView however it never iterates over the items in the collection provided. The arguments coming into the HistoryCustomArrayAdapter always have the position/index of 0. I expect this number it increment as it iterates over the list allowing me to select the correct item in the collection to generate a view for.

I have tried numerous different implementations (ListFragment) but always come to this same point. My logging shows I have the correct number of items in my collection being passed into the HistoryCustomArrayAdapter so I don't feel like this is a problem with the data not being loaded in time for rendering. I have attached the associated logging below.

```
public class HistoryActivity extends BaseMenuActivity implements BaseMenuFragment.OnBaseMenuClickListener{

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HistoryActivity.class.getSimpleName());


  private void initializeDefaultView(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    FragmentUtils.applyContentAndTitleFragments(this, new HistoryContentFragment(), new HistoryMenuFragment());
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        setHistoryButtionActive(findViewById(R.id.base_menu_fragement_container));
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
        setHistoryButtionActive(findViewById(R.id.base_menu_fragement_container));
  }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeDefaultView(savedInstanceState);
    }


}


public class HistoryContentFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HistoryContentFragment.class.getSimpleName());

    public HistoryContentFragment() {
        super();
    }

  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      logger.debug("Creating custom history content view");
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_content_fragement, container, false);

      ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.history_items_list_container);
      List<Custom> customs = getAllCustoms();
      logger.debug("Count of customs to add to adapter ["+customs.size()+"]");
      HistoryCustomArrayAdapter adapter = new HistoryCustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.history_item_fragment, customs);
      listview.setAdapter(adapter);
      return view;
    }

    private static List<Custom> getAllCustoms(){
      List<Custom> customs = new Select().from(Custom.class).execute();
      return customs;
    }
}


public class HistoryCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Custom>{

  private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
  private static final SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HistoryCustomArrayAdapter.class.getSimpleName());

  private final Context context;
  private final List<Custom> values;
  private int textViewResourceId;

  public class ViewHolder {
    ImageView activityImage;
    TextView locationText;
    TextView dateText;
    TextView timeText;

  }

  public HistoryCustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Custom> values) {
      super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
      this.context = context;
      this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
      this.values = values;
      logger.debug("Initialized from this constructor");
  }

  /**
   * The number of items in the list is determined by the number of speeches
   * in our array.
   *
   * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getCount()
   */
  public int getCount() {
      return values.size();
  }

  /**
   * Since the data comes from an array, just returning the index is
   * sufficent to get at the data. If we were using a more complex data
   * structure, we would return whatever object represents one row in the
   * list.
   *
   * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItem(int)
   */
  public Custom getItem(int position) {
      return values.get(position);
  }

  /**
   * Use the array index as a unique id.
   *
   * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItemId(int)
   */
  public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
  }


  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    logger.debug("Position ["+position+"]\n"+this.getCount());
    ViewHolder holder;
    Custom Custom = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      convertView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(textViewResourceId, null);

      holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.activityImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.history_item_activity_btn);
      holder.dateText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.history_item_date);
      holder.timeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.history_item_time);
      holder.locationText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.history_item_location);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    addCustomLocation(Custom,holder);
    addCustomThumbs(Custom,holder);
    addCustomActivity(Custom,holder);
    addRtatingTimeDate(Custom,holder);
    return convertView;
  }

  private void addCustomThumbs(Custom Custom, ViewHolder viewHolder){

  }

  private void addCustomConnectionType(Custom Custom, ViewHolder viewHolder){

  }

  private void addCustomActivity(Custom Custom, ViewHolder viewHolder){

  }

  private void addRtatingTimeDate(Custom Custom, ViewHolder viewHolder){
  }

  private void addCustomLocation(Custom Custom, ViewHolder viewHolder){

  }

}
```

OFFENDING MAIN LAYOUT RESOURCE (activity_main.xml)

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/main_content_fragement_scrolling_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/main_content_fragement_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

SOLUTION MAIN LAYOUT history_activity.xml (pull into own layout resource and remove ScrollView):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content_fragement_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragments in use; yes, I know I spelled fragment incorrectly...like everywhere :)

history_content_fragement.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/history_activity_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/history_items_list_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

history_item_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/history_item_general_info"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/history_item_peg_pin"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:paddingRight="5dp"
          android:paddingBottom="5dp"
          android:src="@drawable/tnd_peg_pin" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/history_item_location"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignTop="@id/history_item_peg_pin"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/history_item_peg_pin"
            style="@style/HistoryHeaderLiteTheme" />
  </RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/history_item_details"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/history_item_activity_type"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignTop="@id/history_item_connection_type"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/history_item_connection_type" >

          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/history_item_activity_btn"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      </RelativeLayout>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/history_item_date"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignTop="@id/history_item_activity_type"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            style="@style/HistoryLiteTheme" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/history_item_time"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@id/history_item_date"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            style="@style/HistoryLiteTheme" />
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Logs:

```
05-07 12:21:54.604: D/AbsListView(10938): Get MotionRecognitionManager
05-07 12:21:54.614: D/HistoryContentFragment(10938): Count of custom to add to adapter [5]
05-07 12:21:54.614: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): Initialized from this constructor
05-07 12:21:54.624: D/HistoryMenuFragment(10938): onStart
05-07 12:21:54.624: D/HistoryMenuFragment(10938): onResume
05-07 12:21:54.644: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): Position [0]
05-07 12:21:54.644: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): 5
05-07 12:21:54.654: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): Position [0]
05-07 12:21:54.654: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): 5
05-07 12:21:54.694: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): Position [0]
05-07 12:21:54.694: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): 5
05-07 12:21:54.704: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): Position [0]
05-07 12:21:54.704: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): 5
05-07 12:21:54.704: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): Position [0]
05-07 12:21:54.704: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): 5
05-07 12:21:54.724: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): Position [0]
05-07 12:21:54.724: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): 5
05-07 12:21:54.734: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): Position [0]
05-07 12:21:54.734: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): 5
05-07 12:21:54.794: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): Position [0]
05-07 12:21:54.794: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): 5
05-07 12:21:54.804: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): Position [0]
05-07 12:21:54.804: D/HistoryCustomArrayAdap*(10938): 5
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you put a log entry just before returning `return customs;` in the `getAllCustoms` method and check the size?

Comment: Essentially that is what I have provided for in the 2nd line of the log output: logger.debug("Count of customs to add to adapter ["+customs.size()+"]"); which is just after the usage of getAllCustoms  method. The size returns 5, and I also output this size of the collection on each call to the getView method inside the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: As a note on the getView method invocation from inside the ArrayAdapter: It executes more than the expected number of items in the collection, and I can't seem to make heads or tails of that. Obviously I haven't jumped in with a debugger as of yet, have other more pressing issues to work on ATM.

Comment: Yeap, my request was completely useless. The `ListView` will call the adapter getView()'s method to obtain some children for measurement(especially if you use `wrap_content` for the height of the `ListView`). The behavior seems very strange, I don't see why it would happen. Also how does the `ListView` appear, it contains duplicates or just one row?

Comment: Just one row. I can provide XML if you think that would be useful.

Comment: Not related to this strange problem, but I suggst you to inflate the row in this way: `convertView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(textViewResourceId, parent, false);`. In this way for the inflater will be easier to measure your view.

Comment: Will make adjustment, thanks.

Comment: So, I notice the scrollbar handle on view initialization looks like it may be a indication of the number of Custom list items involved. Point is, I feel like the layout is constricting around the first item and all the others are hidden somehow.

Comment: I was correct! So hardcoding the ListView in the XML layout_height to 400dp revealed the hidden listview items... now I can figure this out.

Comment: Core of the problem was that this fragment was being loaded into a ScrollView (reusing another activities layout resource). All is good now, very odd behavior for this problem though.